Compile failed when trying to compile
I am getting this error when trying to compile the codes of this GitHub repo.
ParserError: Expected ':' but got ','
  --> contracts/RandomIpfsNft.sol:76:16:
   |
76 |       i_gasLane,
   |                ^


Error HH600: Compilation failed


It should be like:
requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({
                keyHash: i_gasLane,
                subId: i_subscriptionId,
                requestConfirmations: REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
                callbackGasLimit: i_callbackGasLimit,
                numWords: NUM_WORDS,
                extraArgs: ""
            })
        );

I've created this PR by pushing this change as well as other required corrections and replaced the import and usage of VRFCoordinatorV2Interface (i.e., VRF v2) with IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus (i.e., VRF v2.5), because VRF v2 is about to be deprecated.

It is showing multiple red lines

Where exactly? Can you please add screenshot by editing your question?

Done, I have added the pictures

Have you added any Solidity extension in your VSCode? Please try installing the Solidity: Nomic Foundation extension and reopen your VSCode.

@EddiePumpin as Syed mentions having the right tooling in VSCode will help diagnose the issues.  Red lines are usually IDE warnings that the code is has compilation issues or other errors (depending on how you've set up the IDE to 'complain')
It appears you're following a tutorial that is a bit older - the risk is that things change fast and makes things outdated.  Common problem. Best way to unblock in these circumstances is to take the time to read the docs and see changes. For eg: changes in VRF from V2->2.5 are here: https://docs.chain.link/vrf/v2-5/migration-from-v2

@ZeusLawyer, thanks for the comment. Yeah, in my PR, I migrated the imports and usages of VRF v2 to v2.5.

Thanks man, I really appreciate
